# Draw a border and clip its children

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm having a requirement of draw a border around a parent layout in `Xamarin.Android` it can be any layout like `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout` etc.

I have achieved this by using GradientDrawable  - Which is just like setting a background for the layout  with a shape.

So my requirement will be achieved

[image]

Query

When setting corner radius for the border, it is not clipping the children. How to clip the children or any other way alternative to do the both? Kindly share your suggestion on this.?

Note: I have tried with `ClipChildren`, `ClipToPadding` for the layout.

[image]
PS: Above images are mentioned for illustration purpose, they are not the exact output.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `ClipToOutline = true;` for the parent, resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can clip the view using canvas. Use ClipPath(path) method of Canvas to clip the required area.

Syntax:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.AddCircle(200,200,100,Direction.CW);
canvas.ClipPath(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`ViewOutlineProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html) API. As an example usage see [ClippingBasic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ClippingBasic) project.

Having defined outline provider class as such:

```
    private class OvalOutlineProvider extends ViewOutlineProvider {
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
            outline.setOval(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        }
    }
```

Then apply view outline to parent:

```
    View parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
    parent.setOutlineProvider(new OvalOutlineProvider());
    parent.setClipToOutline(true);
```

`ViewOutlineProvider` is accessible starting from API 21. Not sure, whether the solution is applicable for Xamarin (hope it does).